# Code worked until more was added - now getting a NameError

Tags: python, canopy

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
#displays title

print ("          H___________________________________________   ")
print ("/========/| █░█ █▀▀█ █▀▀█ █░░ █▀▀█ █▀▀▄ █▀▀▄ \ ")
print ("|||||||||||-█̶▀̶▄̶ ̶█̶░̶░̶█̶ ̶█̶░̶░̶█̶ ̶█̶░̶░̶ ̶█̶▄̶▄̶█̶ ̶█̶░̶░̶█̶ ̶█̶░̶░̶█̶ -\ ")
print ("\========\|_▀̲░̲▀̲ ̲▀̲▀̲▀̲▀̲ ̲▀̲▀̲▀̲▀̲ ̲▀̲▀̲▀̲ ̲▀̲░̲░̲▀̲ ̲▀̲░̲░̲▀̲ ̲▀̲▀̲▀̲░̲ __\ ")
print ("          H ")
print ("          = ")

#intro
print ("Welcom to the land of kool")

#asks your name
name = input ("Can you tell me your name!")

#says hello
print ("Well hello",name,"!")
```

Error displayed:

```
NameError: name '______' is not defined
```

Comment: I can't read your code and I don't understand your question.

Comment: What version of Python are you using?

Comment: Also, please show a sample run. You can copy and paste this from your console. Be sure to include four spaces at the beginning of each line from the output.

Comment: I get no exceptions.

Comment: @nawi That's probably because your using Python 3.x and the OP is using Python 2.x. Which means that the OP needs to use `raw_input()` instead of `input()`.

Comment: @leaf- you are right! I m using Python3.

Answer (score 3):

Depending on the version of Python you are using you may need to use..

`name = raw_input("Can you tell me your name!")`

Check this out for reference.
[What's the difference between raw_input() and input() in python3.x?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4915361/whats-the-difference-between-raw-input-and-input-in-python3-x)

Answer (score 1):

### TL;DR

Use `raw_input()` instead of `input()` in Python 2.x, because `input()` is "shorthand" for `eval(raw_input))`.

---

In Python 2.7, you need to use `raw_input()` instead of `input()`. `raw_input()` lets you read in user input as a string, while `input()` is "shorthand" for `eval(raw_input())` which attempts to evaluate you user input as literal Python code

This is documented in the python 2.x documentation:

> [`input()` is] Equivalent to `eval(raw_input(prompt))`.
>
> This function does not catch user errors. If the input is not syntactically valid, a `SyntaxError` will be raised. Other exceptions may be raised if there is an error during evaluation.
>
> If the readline module was loaded, then input() will use it to provide elaborate line editing and history features.
>
> Consider using the `raw_input()` function for general input from users.

This however was later changed in Python 3.x. In Python 3.x `raw_input()` became `input()` and the old input(`eval(raw_input())`) was dropped. This is documented in [What's new in Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.0.html):

> PEP 3111: `raw_input()` **was renamed to** `input()`. That is, the new `input()` function reads a line from `sys.stdin` and returns it with the trailing newline stripped. It raises `EOFError` if the input is terminated prematurely. To get the old behavior of `input()`, use `eval(input())`.

<sub>(Emphasis mine)</sub>

---

So use `raw_input()` instead of `input()` in Python 2.x, because `input()` is "shorthand" for `eval(raw_input))`. eg. Change:

`name = input ("Can you tell me your name!")`

to

`name = raw_input ("Can you tell me your name!")`